# Retrieve mp3's ID3 Only

Tags: c#, mp3, web-crawler

I want to build mp3 search engine site. it have much urls in my database after crawling.

After that, I check all HTTP header. But i got only the *Content-Length* and *Content-Type*. How to get the complete ID3, friends ?
But i don't want to download the  real file

Maybe stream the part of file and decode the bits ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Content-Length` and `Content-Type` headers of the HTTP request have nothing to do with the ID3-tags of the MP3 file. To get that you need to download the file.
As ID3 can be at the end of the file you very likely also need to download the whole file. You could try to download the e.g. first xx kB of the file, check for a ID3v2 and only download the rest if there isn't one...

Comment: But how if the it has 1,000,000 url ? Is impossible to download all mp3 files before. its bring my server down

Comment: Then you need more server power or time. You don't need "hard-disk space" as you do not need to save the files...

Comment: I host my site on shared hosting. so i have to save the bandwidith too

Comment: Sorry - wrong HW for the wrong Job! You can't build a skyscraper with a bucket and a hand-shovel - except you have the time, lots of time...

Comment: ohh thanks i'll do your suggestion. i will upgrade my hosting

Comment: but i found on google that we can stream the part of mp3 files. how about find the frame ? forget about id3. now i have to get its bitrate

Comment: Read into the structure of the file and then you know what you need to request...